# Azure - CentOS - Secure VM to VM communication

Tags: azure, encryption

We are setting up infrastructure in Azure with Hub-n-spoke model and planning to implement hub-n-spoke model with one hub and two spoke.  The requirement is,

— Spoke to Spoke communication to be secure: The communication between spoke (VNET-to-VNET) will happen through VNET peering, and we found that MACsec encryption at layer2 gets applied by MS Azure by default.  I think we are good on this, correct me if I am missing something. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-overview#data-link-layer-encryption-in-azure)

— Communication between VMs inside VNET to be secured: We see some guidance from MS Azure for Windows VMs to make use of SMB3.0 for securing data in transit between the VM inside VNET. However, we don't see any recommendation or guidance from MS Azure to secure data in transit between Linux (CentOS) VM within VNET.  Any inputs to achieve this would be a great help.

**Note**: As per the [article](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit) from gooogle (especially referring to the [diagram](https://cloud.google.com/images/security/whitepaper-transit-01.svg)), we see VM to VM communication gets encrypted by default inside GCP VPC. We are looking for similar feature in Azure. Please share inputs on this to achieve.

Comment: If the question sounds like `encryption in transit`, usually the best answer is TLS (ssl, https,..). The SMB3.0 enables use of encrypted traffic too, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/files-smb-protocol

Comment: @gusto2, thanks for the response.  What we are looking for is there any in-built Azure feature (or) module which encrypts VM-to-VM communication by default, especially for CentOS (Linux) , similar to GCP.

Comment: There is no guarantee about encrypting the internal VNet traffic in Azure . You need to use TLS is you need/want that.